# Calculating the Probability given multiple guessers

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

I was going through a thought experiment the other day and the following is my problem:

Lets say Students A-F are answering a T/F question on a 10 question exam.

All of the students are on the 10th question, which is of similar difficulty to 1-9.
Student A has a score of 5/9 (55%) thinks #10 is **True**.
Student B has a score of 8/9 (88%) thinks #10 is **True**.
Student C has a score of 8/9 (88%) thinks #10 is **False**.
Student D has a score of 4/9 (44%) thinks #10 is **True**.
Student E has a score of 6/9 (66%) thinks #10 is **False**.

Let say that Student F is guessing on this exam and knows this information.

Based on the other students percentages, are you able to calculate the confidence in which True is the right answer by knowing how the other students performed on the previous questions?

or

How does Student Bs performance on the previous questions (given that they're of the same difficulty) impact the probability that his answer for the 10th is correct? Would it be just 88% for him to get the 10th question right?
And if that previous question is solvable, what is the combined probability of all 5 students that True is correct given what we know they know?

My initial thought was:
While it is independent, it does not seem to make sense to multiply the probabilities by each other. That would be the probability that all of them guess True given the probabilities of them choosing True. Would it just be an average instead?

Could someone clarify this math?
*Note: this is not based on any sort of real life scenario.*

Comment: These scores, is this how many questions the student got right in the first 9 questions of the exam?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes